# Xamarin Forms set a ToolBarItem icon to a resource image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set the icon for a `ToolBarItem` to an image loaded from an embedded resource in my Xamarin Forms project. Something like this:

`SearchToolbarItem.Icon = ImageSource.FromResource("Namespace.folder.imagename.png");`

I am aware that this does not compile, but it gets to heart of what I am trying to do; set an icon to an image loaded from an embedded resource.

I know I could add the image to each individual project (e.g. iOS, Android, etc.) and reference it via a string, but I would prefer just to have one image in the Xamarin Forms project and just use that. Thanks!Q

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is to create link of the png file in Android resources. Then you just use it as local native resource.